# Group by after a partition by in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, partition-by

I am working on some car accident data and am stuck on how to get the data in the form I want.

```sql
select
    sex_of_driver,
    accident_severity,
    count(accident_severity) over (partition by sex_of_driver, accident_severity) 
from
    SQL.dbo.accident as accident
    inner join SQL.dbo.vehicle as vehicle on
        accident.accident_index = vehicle.accident_index
```

This is my code, which counts the accidents had per each sex for each severity. I know I can do this with group by but I wanted to use a partition by in order to work out % too.

However I get a very large table (I assume for each row that is each sex/severity.  When I do the following:

```sql
select
    sex_of_driver,
    accident_severity,
    count(accident_severity) over (partition by sex_of_driver, accident_severity) 
from
    SQL.dbo.accident as accident
    inner join SQL.dbo.vehicle as vehicle on
        accident.accident_index = vehicle.accident_index
group by
    sex_of_driver,
    accident_severity
```

I get this:

| sex_of_driver | accident_severity | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| -1 | 2 | 1 |
| -1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |

I won't give you the whole table, but basically, the group by has caused the count to just be 1.

I can't figure out why group by isn't working.  Is this an MS SQL-Server thing?

I want to get the same result as below (obv without the CASE etc)

```
select
    accident.accident_severity,
    count(accident.accident_severity) as num_accidents,
    vehicle.sex_of_driver,
    CASE vehicle.sex_of_driver WHEN '1' THEN 'Male' WHEN '2' THEN 'Female' end as sex_col,
    CASE accident.accident_severity WHEN '1' THEN 'Fatal' WHEN '2' THEN 'Serious' WHEN '3' THEN 'Slight' end as serious_col
from
    SQL.dbo.accident as accident
    inner join SQL.dbo.vehicle as vehicle on
        accident.accident_index = vehicle.accident_index
where
    sex_of_driver != 3
    and
    sex_of_driver != -1

group by
    accident.accident_severity,
    vehicle.sex_of_driver

order by
    accident.accident_severity
```

Comment: Why are you using `count(accident_severity)`?

Comment: `inner join SQL.dbo.vehicle as vehicle on accident.accident_index = vehicle.accident_index` <-- This is either a bug or your DB is not normalized. What is `vehicle`'s primary-key?

Comment: Why is `sex_of_driver` an integer column (`int`?) instead of, say `char(1)`?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` anyway?

Comment: I wanted to count the number of each sex that had each severity of accident.

Comment: Then use `COUNT( DISTINCT sex_of_driver )`

Comment: "Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause."

Comment: Let's take a step back for a moment... what final output do you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding here.

`GROUP BY` will reduce your rows to a single row per grouping (ie per pair of `sex_of_driver, accident_severity` values. Any normal aggregates you use with this, such as `COUNT(*)`, will return the aggregate value *within* that group.

Whereas `OVER` gives you a windowed aggregated, and means you are calculating it *after* reducing your rows. Therefore when you write `count(accident_severity) over (partition by sex_of_driver, accident_severity)` the aggregate only receives a single row in each partition, because the rows have already been reduced.

You say "I know I can do this with group by but I wanted to use a partition by in order to work out % too." but you are misunderstanding how to do that. You don't need `PARTITION BY` to work out percentage. All you need to calculate a percentage over the whole resultset is `COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()`, in other words a windowed aggregate *over* a normal aggregate.

Note also that `count(accident_severity)` does not give you the number of *distinct* `accident_severity` values, it gives you the number of non-null values, which is probably not what you intend. You also have a very strange join predicate, you probably want something like `a.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id`

So you want something like this:

```sql
select
    sex_of_driver,
    accident_severity,
    count(*) as Count,
    count(*) * 1.0 /
      sum(count(*)) over (partition by sex_of_driver) as PercentOfSex
    count(*) * 1.0 /
      sum(count(*)) over () as PercentOfTotal
from
    dbo.accident as accident a
    inner join dbo.vehicle as v on
        a.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id
group by
    sex_of_driver,
    accident_severity;
```